# Gtk+ accel group callback function problem

Tags: c, gtk3

I am a newbie in GTK+ and I do not understand what's wrong with my callback function. Could you help me please?

I want to change my box orientation, but somehow my box pointer is wrong inside my callback function.

My code:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void flip_buttons(GtkWidget *window, gpointer user_data) {
  gtk_orientable_set_orientation(
                 GTK_BOX(user_data),
                 GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *button2;

    gtk_init (&argc,&argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Btn A");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Btn B");

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GClosure* closure_flip_buttons =
      g_cclosure_new(G_CALLBACK(flip_buttons), box, 0);

    // Set up the accelerator group.
    GtkAccelGroup* accel_group = gtk_accel_group_new();

    gtk_accel_group_connect(accel_group,
                            GDK_KEY_F,
                            GDK_CONTROL_MASK,
                            0,
                            closure_flip_buttons);

    gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), accel_group);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Error while compiling:

```sh
gtk_accel_error.c: In function ‘flip_buttons’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2277:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_orientable_set_orientation’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:482:66: note: in expansion of macro ‘_G_TYPE_CIC’
 #define G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST(instance, g_type, c_type)    (_G_TYPE_CIC ((instance), (g_type), c_type))
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbox.h:40:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST’
 #define GTK_BOX(obj)            (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_BOX, GtkBox))
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Ok, added my error, updated my issue description.

Comment: You have passed a wrong parameter in `gtk_orientable_set_orientation`. Take a look at the function's signature from the docs: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Orientable.html#gtk-orientable-set-orientation

Comment: Could you help me what's wrong? I cannot see it.

Comment: If I change it to this:
(GtkOrientable *)user_data

Then it compiles, but then I get this error when I run it:

Gtk-CRITICAL **: 10:51:36.721: gtk_orientable_set_orientation: assertion 'GTK_IS_ORIENTABLE (orientable)' failed

Comment: `gpointer user_data` should be `GtkOrientable * user_data`

Comment: No, if I modify it as you suggested like this:

void flip_buttons(GtkWidget *window, GtkOrientable *user_data) {
  gtk_orientable_set_orientation(
     user_data,
     GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
}

I got the same error.

Comment: What if, instead of `(GtkOrientable *)user_data`, you use `GTK_ORIENTABLE(user_data)`?

Comment: Then we have a new error message:

```c
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:57:10.769: invalid cast from 'GtkAccelGroup' to 'GtkOrientable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accel-group-connect), the signature for your closure has to be:

```
gboolean
(*GtkAccelGroupActivate) (GtkAccelGroup *accel_group,
                          GObject *acceleratable,
                          guint keyval,
                          GdkModifierType modifier);
```

I think that means your function needs to look something like this:

```
gboolean flip_buttons(GtkAccelGroup *accel_group,
                  GObject *acceleratable,
                  guint keyvalue,
                  GdkModifierType modifier,
                  gpointer user_data)
{
  gtk_orientable_set_orientation(
                 GTK_ORIENTABLE(user_data),
                 GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
  return TRUE;
}
```

However, you might need to play around with that. The warning indicated that your user_data--the second argument in the call--was a GtkAccelGroup. But I thought the second parameter in the signature would end up being the window, so I don't know.

Comment: Works perfectly, indeed you have the point. Thank you for your help and explanation now its clear.